# Creation of an input dialog using Kivy

Tags: android, python, kivy

I would like to create a function which only returns its value once the user input text into a TextInput and click on an ok button.  For example

```
n = PopupInput("What number should I add?")
print 5+n
```

I can't figure out how to write a kivy dialog which will pause execution and wait until the user closes it.  In other GUI toolkits, I would have used something like

```
while True:
   if dialog.visable == False:
      return int(textbox.text)
   else:
       wx.Yield()
```

To allow my code to just sit in one spot while allowing the GUI framework to do its thing.  However, I can find no equivalent method for Kivy.

EDIT:

Here's my unsuccessful attempt (its messy)

```
def PopupOk(text, title='', btn_text='Continue'):
    btnclose = Button(text=btn_text, size_hint_y=None, height='50sp')
    content = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
    p = Popup(title=title, content=content, size=('300dp', '300dp'),
                size_hint=(None, None))
    content.add_widget(Label(text=text))
    ti = TextInput(height='50sp', font_size='50sp', input_type='number')
    content.add_widget(ti)
    def _on_d(*args):
        p.is_visable = False
    p.bind(on_dismiss=_on_d)
    p.is_visable = True

    content.add_widget(btnclose)

    btnclose.bind(on_release=p.dismiss)
    p.open()
    while not p.is_visable:
        EventLoop.idle()
   return ti.text
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would think about this the other way around - what you *really* want to do is print the number when the popup is closed.

Assuming you have a popup with a textinput for the user to write in, you can do `popup.bind(on_dismiss=some_function)` to run that `some_function` when the popup is closed. That means all you need to do is write a function that takes a popup, retrieves the textbox text, and prints whatever answer you want.

I'm not sure how directly this fits with whatever you're really trying to do, but it's a more natural way to work with Kivy's event system. I can maybe answer differently if you have some strongly different requirement.

Edit: Seeing your edit, this is almost what you do, but I think it is a bad idea to try and beat the eventloop into submission this way rather than going with the flow. I would create a new function (as I said above) that takes a textinput and does whatever you really want. By binding `on_dismiss` to this function, you let kivy take care of starting your computation later whenever the user gets around to dismissing the popup.

Comment: Thanks @inclement.  I've read some examples that follow that paradigm, but it won't well for me because what happens is the user pushes a button -- which calls a function -- and some calcs are done which then brings up the prompt which would then return to where I left off in that function.  I'd prefer to not to have to split this function into two halves for readabilitie's sake.

Comment: I thought about it, but I don't really have any better idea than what I suggested, it seems very natural to me. To be honest I'm not convinced the paradigm is wrong for you, but it's your choice and I certainly can't claim to be an authority on it.

Comment: It just seems so weird to me this can't be done.  It's pretty standard in other GUI frameworks to have simple dialogs and call a function to get the user's response to the prompt.  Just surprised there's not clean way to do it in Kivy.  Thanks for the help, as always.  (BTW, thanks for answering so many Kivy questions on SO; I've found them invaluable)

Answer (score 1):

Kivy is really built around the principle of events and async callbacks. Because it uses OpenGL and relies upon frames rendered on the GPU, not the CPU, you never want to use blocking code. So kivy uses event binding to circumvent the issue.

Here is one approach.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.button = Button(text="Click",
                             on_release=self.get_caption)
        return self.button

    def get_caption(self, btn):
        Popup(title="Enter text here",
              content=TextInput(focus=True),
              size_hint=(0.6, 0.6),
              on_dismiss=self.set_caption).open()

    def set_caption(self, popup):
        self.button.text = popup.content.text

MainApp().run()
```

You place content in a popup, when give it a "set_caption" function to call when it's dismissed. There you respond to the change. No blocking. No waiting. Having worked with threading to stop GUI blocking in wxWidgets, I really think this is a better way...;-)

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for can be achieved with the following code. You need to specify routines as methods in the main program:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.5.0') # replace with your current kivy version !
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.clock import Clock

class YourApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Button(text='Press for popup!', on_press=self.callpopup)

    def callpopup(self, event):
        dlg = MessageBox(titleheader="Titel Header", message="Any Message", options={"YES": "printyes()", "NO": "printno()"})
        print "Messagebox shows as kivy popup and we wait for the \nuser action and callback to go to either routine"

    def printyes(self):
        # routine for going yes
        print "You chose the Yes routine"

    def printno(self):
        # routine for going no
        print "You chose the No routine"

class MessageBox(YourApp):
    def __init__(self, titleheader="Title", message="Message", options={"OK": "self.ok()", "NO": "self.no()"}):

        def popup_callback(instance):
            "callback for button press"
            # print('Popup returns:', instance.text)
            self.retvalue = instance.text
            self.popup.dismiss()

        self.retvalue = None
        self.options = options
        box = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        box.add_widget(Label(text=message, font_size=20))
        b_list =  []
        buttonbox = BoxLayout(orientation='horizontal')
        for b in options:
            b_list.append(Button(text=b, size_hint=(1,.35), font_size=20))
            b_list[-1].bind(on_press=popup_callback)
            buttonbox.add_widget(b_list[-1])
        box.add_widget(buttonbox)
        self.popup = Popup(title=titleheader, content=box, size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))
        self.popup.open()
        self.popup.bind(on_dismiss=self.OnClose)

    def OnClose(self, event):
        self.popup.unbind(on_dismiss=self.OnClose)
        self.popup.dismiss()
        if self.retvalue != None:
            command = "super(MessageBox, self)."+self.options[self.retvalue]
            # print "command", command
            exec command

if __name__ == '__main__':
    YourApp().run()
```